# how to obtain the registration_id for FCM-Django push notifications (flutter app)

Tags: django, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using django as my back end for my flutter app. And just wanted to learn how to implement push notifications.

is there a  way to get the registration_id of a device to send push notifications without adding the firebase_messaging/firebase_core packages to my flutter package? I feel like its excessive to get those packages to just register the device token. Or is this the only way^

I am using the FCM-django package to send notifications but need to save the registration_id of the device for each user in my database.

Comment: Hello @Karan, I am facing the exact same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: hey yes i did. so you do have to add firebase_messaging and firebase_core packages. its the easiest way.  
You then gotta register your app on firebase because essentially youre using their service of push notifications. this part requries you to follow their instructions (android vs ios) theres a file you have to add into your app that they generate for you.
You also have to set up your backend as well. i ran into a problem where my django backend was not able to recognize the file that they make you add as a system variable. so make sure to restart your computer once you do.

Comment: i did everthing but i am not sure how to send the registration id for fcm model in django backend? or is that to leave for frontend developer and i dont have to do anything from backend??

Comment: yup thats front end!.

They have to get the registration id and send it !

Comment: ok thanks!...can you tell me how to test it for now?? I have done the backend part using django but the frontend part is stiill to be done? Now how to test if my backend code is correct?? without making frontend part??

Comment: I would just set up the front end . So you can easily see the notification pop up! I think that's the best way to go about it. Firebase messaging, firebase core, get the required packages, initialise the packages on flutter . And obtain that registration Id Send the Id to the back end to save a FCM device associated with a user. Then you'll be able to send the push notification. Let me know if you got any specific questions.

Comment: thanks karan, i have a question..is firebase totally free, ie if our project runs for like 10 years , a million notifications might be sent..can we do that we firebase?? or we have to buy a premium at one point??

Comment: so im super new to this as well. but firebase messaging is totally free.  i feel like theres always some hidden fees so i Haven't looked into it fully. but it seems free for now. i feel like anything can change tho

Answer (score 1):

To Get Device Token in Flutter

```
    final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    @override
    void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _fcm.getToken().then((value) {
       print("Device Token ${value}");
    });
    }
```

Store this device token into the database and use it for the push notification.